# Spark: Output operation after mapWithSate

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

We have spark streaming application where we consume events from Kafka ..we want to aggregate the event's over a period of time by the traceid in each event and create an aggregate event for that traceid and write the aggreagated event into a database

our events are like this

```
traceid: 123
{
  info: abc;
}

traceid: 123
{
  info:bcd;
}
```

Now what we want to achieve is create an aggregate event over a period of time say 2mins and **write the aggregated event into database instead of individual event's**

```
traceid: 123
{
   info:abc,bcd
}
```

we used **mapwithState** and came up with this code

```
 def trackStateFunc(batchTime: Time, id: String, url: Option[MetricTypes.EnrichedKeyType], state: State[SessionData]): Option[(String, String, Long, immutable.Map[String, String])] = {

    val enrichedId = id

    var accountId:String = null
    var reducedText:String = null
    var commonIDS:String = null
    var deviceId:String = null
    var ets:Long = 0
    var eventId:String = null

    if (url.isDefined) {
      accountId = url.get._1.asInstanceOf[String]
      reducedText = url.get._2.asInstanceOf[String]
      commonIDS = url.get._3.asInstanceOf[String]
      deviceId = url.get._4.asInstanceOf[String]
      ets = url.get._5.toString.toLong
      eventId = url.get._6.asInstanceOf[String]

      val attributeMap = Map(
        eventId -> reducedText,
        "common_ids" -> commonIDS,
        "common_enriched_physicalDeviceId" -> deviceId
      )

      if (state.exists) {
        val newState = state.get.attributeMap ++ attributeMap
        state.update(SessionData(newState))
        Some(accountId, enrichedId, ets, newState)
      } else {
        state.update(SessionData(attributeMap))
        Some(accountId, enrichedId, ets, attributeMap)
      }
    }
    else {
      None
    }

  }

    val stateSpec = StateSpec.function(trackStateFunc _).timeout(Minutes(2)).


    val requestsWithState = tempLines.mapWithState(stateSpec)


    requestsWithState.foreachRDD { rdd =>
        rdd.foreachPartition { partitionOfRecords =>
          val connection = createNewConnection()
          partitionOfRecords.foreach(record => { record match {


        case (accountId, enrichedId, ets, attributeMap) =>

          if (validateRecordForStorage(accountId, enrichedId, ets, attributeMap)) {
            val ds = new DBDataStore(connection)
            ds.saveEnrichedEvent(accountId, enrichedId, ets, attributeMap)
            //val r = scala.util.Random

          } else {

            /*logError("Discarded record [enrichedId=" + enrichedId
                + ", accountId=" + accountId
                + ", ets=" + ets
                + ", attributes=" + attributeMap.toString() + "]")*/
            println("Discarded record [enrichedId=" + enrichedId
              + ", accountId=" + accountId
              + ", ets=" + ets
              + "]")

            null
          }

        case default => {
          logInfo("You gave me: " + default)
          null
        }
      }

      }

      )

        }
    }
```

the mapwithState aggregates fine ...but our understanding is ..it should start writing to the database **only after 2 min's** but ..noticing that it **start's writing immediately to the database without waiting for 2mins** .....so definitely our understanding is not right if someone can please guide us in achieving our goal of writing to database **only after aggregating for 2mins** would greatly help

Comment: Add your track state function

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov added trackstateFunc please let us know if you need more info